# Is this a valid way to filter to Unique Values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have inherited a legacy piece of code and do not understand why this code bloc is throwing an Assertion Error, any help is really appreciated!

```
# rename columns and filter out null values
df_cipSP_PP = cipSP_PP_raw.rename(columns={'Asset/Tag Number': 'cipSP UID'})
df_cipSP_PP_select = df_cipSP_PP.loc[df_cipSP_PP['cipSP UID'].notnull()].copy()
df_cipSP_PP_select['cipSP UID'] = df_cipSP_PP_select['cipSP UID'].astype(str)

# take only one unique uid, eliminating nulls
df_cipSP_PP_rolled = df_cipSP_PP_select.groupby(by='cipSP UID').max().reset_index()

# merge farf against cip sharepoint
PP_sources = pd.merge(how='left', left=PP_farf_cipacc_other2, right=df_cipSP_PP_rolled['cipSP UID'].to_frame(),
                      left_on='FARF TAG', right_on='cipSP UID')
PP_sources = PP_sources.rename(columns={'cipSP UID': 'CIP'})
```

This is the error code I am trying to resolve

```
 assert len(locs) == result.shape[1]
```

Comment: That line is not the line which throws an assertion error. The assertion error is thrown at the line `assert len(locs) == result.shape[1]` which you put below. You'll need to examine why the condition asserted is not true.

Answer (score 0):

df['column_name'].unique()

This will return all the unique values

df['column_name'].unique().tolist() to have all unique values in a list

Answer (score -1):

This would not filter to unique values. This is grouping items by id, and then only taking one of them (as the command says).

To filter unique values, look at the function: [unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html). It should set you on the right track!